# What practices should I do to get better Organic Search Engine rankings "Google" in Africa?

Tags: seo

I have this site that I manage, I've optimized the site and get good SEO results in South Africa, I however need to get better results from the rest of Africa, and I need to know are there any Guidelines I could follow, eg registering a .com domain, the current domain is a .co.za domain. Any advise will help!

Comment: Does language matter or do most other African countries primarily use English?

Answer (score 4):

I'm in SA myself and I've faced this same problem before. In my experience with dealing with it I've learned that having a .com domain does actually help (it's difficult to judge to what extent, but it definitely makes a clear difference).

Also, in Google Webmaster Tools (I presume your site is registered on there) you can set your website to target either users in SA or global users. There doesn't seem to be an Africa only option, so it's either just us or everyone. This step is basically essential if you want people outside of the country to find you on Google and I've found it to be very useful.

Aside form that you can use AdWords and if memory serves, you can set more specific location targeting in there.

Comment: Yes you can setup specific locations in Adwords.